# How to use normal clauses converted from DCG Prolog one?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I know DCG is only a syntactic sugar , as prolog translate them in normal Clauses.
So, for instance,

```
palindrome --> [].
palindrome --> [_].
palindrome --> [X], palindrome, [X].
/*  it is translated into:  */
palindrome(A, A).
palindrome([_|A], A).
palindrome([X|A], B) :- palindrome(A, C),   C=[X|B].
```

My problem is, I want to avoid, to use the "phrase" clause, and accessing the normal code converting fron the DCG one.
If I try to ask for a palindrome sequence, it simply dosen't work.
For istance:

```
? palindrome([1,2],X).
X = [1, 2] .
```

I'd like to have the same result as:

```
?- phrase(palindrome,[1,2,1]).
true
?- phrase(palindrome,[1,2,X]).
X = 1
```

Without using phrase.
Thanks

Comment: Don't. Avoiding `phrase/2-3` breaks the DCGs abstraction. There's no reason to do so.

Comment: Hi Paulo, there is a reason really, I need to have access to the internal part of the clause, in this case, `palindrome`. 
For instance, the wikipedia example:  `sentence --> noun_phrase, verb_phrase` with   `phrase/2-3`, I only have the value of sentence, meanwhile I need them all, the value of    `noun_phrase` and  `verb_phrase`.

Comment: If by "internal part of the clause" you mean the implicit difference list, you can access it from a grammar rule using lambda expressions or the `call//1` non-terminal.